# Printing echo in file and prompt parallely

Tags: shell-script, solaris, echo

I want to print an echo statement in a log file as well as on prompt.

```
echo "Installation complete" #This is printed on prompt
echo "Installation complete" >> deploy.log #This is printed in log
```

I want to accomplish this in one single command. Is is possible or I am being too ambitious ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo "Installation complete" | tee -a deploy.log`